# SQL Service broker end conversation timeout

Tags: sql-server, timeout, service-broker

I have a service broker application reading messages like this

```
WAITFOR (
    RECEIVE TOP (1)
        conversation_handle
       ,message_type_name
       ,CAST(message_body AS XML)
    FROM @QueueName
), TIMEOUT @Timeout
```

And after receving the message I do

```
END CONVERSATION @Conversation_handle
```

The problem I got is that on a busy server I occationally get a timeout error on `END CONVERSATION`.

> The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the
>   server is not responding. The wait operation timed out

The timeout is the default 30s. I can of course increase the timeout but just want to ensure the problem isn't somewhere else.

i.e. can the timeout happen due to something other than a busy server, e.g. some kind of deadlock?

Comment: It wouldn't be a deadlock since the server monitors for those and kills at least one of the participants in order to keep things moving. As it happens, I've been doing some broker work lately. Are you able to capture the resource that's being waited on (through an extended events session perhaps)? Also, there's a MS whitepaper out there on SB performance that suggests a) re-using conversations (and thus never `END`ing them and b) receiving more than one at a time in order to reduce contention on some system tables. Are either (or both) of these possibilities for you?

Comment: @BenThul, Thank you for your comment. The errors are infrequent so I will just increase the timeout and see if it helps. I was just surpriced an operation could go from ms time to 30+ seconds just because the server is busy. The SQLServer is on another machine so it could be network congestion as well.

Comment: @BenThul, finally figured this out. It is a kind of deadlock! I ended the conversation before reading the message from the data reader buffer, i.e. calling reader.GetSqlXml(2). This worked most of the time because the message fit inside the data reader buffer. When a larger message was received, the conversation was still locked when I tried to end it => dead-lock. (Now I know SqlDataReader.Read() does not read the entire record. Somting I never thought of before)